# How to get postgres plainto_tsquery, but with stems separated by OR (|) instead of AND (&)?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Here is an example `plainto_tsquery` call in postgres 15.1:

```
# select plainto_tsquery('english', 'postgres is the best');
  plainto_tsquery  
-------------------
 'postgr' & 'best'
(1 row)
```

This is the equivalent of

```
select to_tsquery('english', 'postgr & best');
    to_tsquery     
-------------------
 'postgr' & 'best'
```

[The docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html) say

> plainto_tsquery transforms the unformatted text querytext to a tsquery value. The text is parsed and normalized much as for to_tsvector, then the & (AND) tsquery operator is inserted between surviving words.

How do I get the same result (parsed and normalized) from a text phrase, but with `'|'` between the tokens, e.g., the equivalent of

```
# select to_tsquery('english', 'postgr | best');
    to_tsquery     
-------------------
 'postgr' | 'best'
```

but being able to pass in "postgres is the best" as input?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a direct way, but that many conversions isn't good for performance.

Also it is possible to make a string and then make a tsquery from it instead of a String.

```
SELECT string_agg(quote_literal(lexeme)::text, ' | ') 
  FROM  unnest((select   to_tsvector ('english', 'postgres is the best')));
```

| string_agg |
| --- |
| 'best' | 'postgr' |

```
SELECT string_agg(lexeme::text, ' | ')::tsquery 
  FROM  unnest((select   to_tsvector ('english', 'postgres is the best')));
```

| string_agg |
| --- |
| 'best' | 'postgr' |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M63ir-2j)

Answer (score 1):

Use `websearch_to_tsquery()`:

```
select websearch_to_tsquery('english', 'postgres or best');

 websearch_to_tsquery 
══════════════════════
 'postgr' | 'best'
(1 row)
```

Comment: that works for that but in pattern more complex it would fail https://dbfiddle.uk/WPPt12iC

Comment: Well, nothing is perfect. But that's a different question.

Comment: You made this work by changing the input query, but that assumes knowledge of which words to keep, so it doesn't seem like the answer. However, it does suggest that maybe I have to parse the query (stopwords at least) myself, so thanks for this.

Comment: Right, that's the best you'll get. I didn't know that you were stuck with `|`. You could replace the pipe character with `or`.